# Refused to execute script and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, payment, mastercard

I get refused to execute script because of MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

When i integration Mastercard using php curl and JavaScript although no errors appears.

```
    function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    
    function cancelCallback() {
        console.log('Payment cancelled');
    }
    
    var configs = {
        merchant: '<?php echo $merchant; ?>',
        session: {
            "id": '<?php echo $sessionid; ?>',
        },
        order: {
            "amount": '<?php echo $amount; ?>',
            "currency": '<?php echo $currency; ?>',
            "id": '<?php echo $orderid; ?>',
        },
        interaction: {
            "operation": "PURCHASE",
            "merchant": {
                "name": "abc",
                "address": {
                    "line1": "town",
                    "line2": "city"
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    Checkout.configure(configs);
```

Comment: Bro have you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: using jQuery ajax instead of php to send request and it will work fine without errors

Answer (score -2, accepted):

using jquery ajax instead of php curl and no problem found

Comment: While this is a self answer you have not provided any indication code wise of how you completed this action please update this answer to show what you have done, i would more suggest you just delete the question as it no longer relevant to how your implementing the code and there is no accepted answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

PHP will, by default, tell the browser that it is sending it HTML.

If you are writing a PHP program to send something else (such as JSON, XML or JavaScript) then you need to use the [`header()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to override the default `Content-Type` with the correct one.

e.g.

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```